# Apache Guacamole XRDP desktop shows sometimes blurry

Tags: guacamole, xrdp

I'm using Apache Guacamole 1.2.0 and XRDP 0.9.12 on Ubuntu 20.04.

When looking at the remote desktop the fonts are shown sometimes reasonably sharp (alas still less than when opening an RDP connection directly), but often become blurry/blocky, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: blurry RDP desktop]

It's possible to "provoke" this by letting the browser window loosing the input focus. But it also happens while working on the remote desktop. By triggerings repaints (e.g. by going with the mouse over the text) the fonts become sharp again at the repainted screen regions while staying blurry at the other screen regions.

The RDP connection settings in Guacamole are configured like this:

[image: Guac RDP connection settings]

I played a bit with the font smoothing and caching options, but could not improve the situation.
Is there any way to keep the fonts from "going blurry"?

Best regards,

Bernd

Comment: Hai, did you encounter this in chrome?

Comment: @SongLim : I am facing this issue in chrome . Do you have any suggestions to resolve it ?

Comment: Hai, you may try disable `disabled-accelerated-2d-canvas` flag in chrome, and then relaunch. It helps in my case.

Comment: Out of interest, what was the zoom level of your browser set to, can you remember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled with compiled versions xrdp 0.9.14 and xorgxrdp 0.2.14 - I had to do this anyway, because file sharing does not work between Guacamole and xrdp 0.9.12.

As a "side effect", the blocky/blurry appearance is gone now, too.
Either it has been fixed with the newer version or my old installation was somehow faulty.